# Use xmltable Oracle function with multiple default namespaces

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, namespaces

I need to use the Oracle xmltable function to get data from an xmltype column in a table. xml data contains a default namespace. So I'm using this code:

```
xmltable(xmlnamespaces(default 'myDefaultNamespace'),...
```

Now the problem I am facing is that some documents have not the same default namespace (even if they are formatted exactly the same). As a result I will not be able to get all the data with one query, I will have to run a second one with the other namespace as default parameter.

Is there a way to avoid querying two times the table by passing multiple default namespace ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple namespace strings, but only one default string:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm

[image: XMLTable function definition]

[image: XML_namespaces_clause]

Try using multiple strings with the normal one specified as the default, it should work.

Comment: Could you add a code example ? If I add a second namespace string I must use the AS identifier construct and it does not work as the element are not prefixed by the namespace in the xml document.

Comment: If the namespace is not in the document, then it will never work with one query. You can only have one default.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround for my issue, I replace one of the namespace by the other using the replace function in the passing clause of the xmltable function.

```
passing xmltype(replace(t.xml.getClobValue(),'SecondNamespace','MyDefaultNamespace'))
```